# Concatenate arrays from the same array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 10002,
    "flag": false,
    "list": [
      "aaa",
      "bbb"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 10001,
    "flag": true,
    "list": [
      "10002",
      "10003"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 10003,
    "flag": false,
    "list": [
      "ccc",
      "ddd"
    ]
  }
]
```

i tried this 
initially i have "10001" value so iterate this array to take "list" array if flag==true then stored into newarray.  but its not working.

I want it to be like this: `[ "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd" ]`.

Comment: use array.splice

Comment: And what did you try to achieve the desired output?

Comment: i dont follow. you want to concatinate the lists for the same id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const array = [
  {
    id: 10001,
    flag: true,
    list: ["10002", "10003"]
  },
  {
    flag: false,
    id: 10002,
    list: ["aaa", "bbb"]
  },
  {
    flag: false,
    id: 10003,
    list: ["ccc", "ddd"]
  }
];

const isHead = item => item.flag && item.id === 10001;

const head = array.find(isHead);

const rest = array.filter(item => !isHead(item));

const result = rest
  .flatMap(item =>
    head.list.includes(item.id.toString()) && item.list
  );

console.log(result);
```

Comment: yes it is working.. but sometimes data like this ```[
  {
    "id": 10002,
    "flag": false,
    "list": [
      "aaa",
      "bbb"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 10001,
    "flag": true,
    "list": [
      "10002",
      "10003"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 10003,
    "flag": false,
    "list": [
      "ccc",
      "ddd"
    ]
  }
] ```

Comment: If I understood your correctly, first item must be flagged, other shouldn't be?

Comment: we cant take first as head.. may be position changed. so which object has id == 10001 and flag === true only as head array

Answer (score 2):

If i understand correctly this is what you want:

```
const someArray = [
  {
    "id": 10001,
    "list": [
      "10002",
      "10003"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 10002,
    "list": [
      "aaa",
      "bbb"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 10003,
    "list": [
      "ccc",
      "ddd"
    ]
  }
];

const [head,...rest] = someArray;
const result = head.list.reduce((acc,currentId)=>acc.concat(rest.find(({id})=> id === parseInt(currentId)).list),[]);
```

Here is a jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sudakatux/9hju85mt/22/

Explanation:
take the head and splitted from the rest since the head contains the ids.
using the head as a dictionary find each list for each id in the head and concatenate

*note* the id must be in the subsequent list else it will fail with undefined. if you want to account for this error you can set a defualt empty object with a list. for example this part:

```
rest.find(({id})=> id === parseInt(currentId)).list
```

Will look like

```
rest.find(({id})=> id === parseInt(currentId)) || {list:[]}).list
```

Which basically means if its undefined return an object that has an empty list so then it will concatenate an empty list which results in being the same list. (like multiplying by 1 in a multiplication)

Hope it helps.

EDIT after your edit.

If your array is in different order you need to find the dictonary and then the logic is the same

```
  const [newHead] = otherArray.filter(({list}) => list.every(elem=>!isNaN(elem)));

    const result2 = newHead.list.reduce(
    (acc,currentId) =>acc.concat(otherArray.find(({id})=> id === parseInt(currentId)).list),[]);
```

if you are testing for the flag then your head filter would look like. the blocks are the same the only thing that changes is the condition.

```
const [newHead] = otherArray.filter(({flag}) => flag));
```

(note* that instead of using the rest i used the complete array(otherArray). since im targeting equality.
Im using filter and extracting the first element of the result. because im accounting for the possibility that in the future you may have more than one "dictionary element". if thats the case in the future then you just have to concat the lists from the filter result

Comment: we cant take first as head.. may be position changed. so which object has id == 10001 and flag === true only as head array

Answer (score 0):

You can map over the list of the first item and concat all the lists from those ids.

```
const mapItems = (input) => {
  const source = input[0].list;
  source.reduce((results, id) => {
    return results.concat(input.find(item => item.id === id).list);
  }, []);
};

mapItems([
  {
    "id": 10001,
    "list": [
      "10002",
      "10003"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 10002,
    "list": [
      "aaa",
      "bbb"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 10003,
    "list": [
      "ccc",
      "ddd"
    ]
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the values of the list of first object in the array as `arr[0]['list']`
Once you have these values (10002,10003) then you can fetch the list values of remaining objects in the array whose id key matches one of the above values.

```
if(arr[i]['id'] == 10002 || arr[i]['id'] == 10003){
//fetch the list values
}
```